# How to change php from cgi-fcg to php cli on Centos 7

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos7

so basically I have php installed on my server.
When I do:

```
php -v
```

The output is

```
PHP 7.3.25 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Dec  9 2020 03:04:52)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
```

I am trying to run a php code using the command

```
php -r
```

There is the output

```
[root@13-233-227-17 ~]# php -r *myPhpCode*
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
Usage: php-cgi [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php-cgi <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
  -T <count>       Measure execution time of script repeated <count> times.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As described in error message the command `php -r` demand peace of PHP code as parameter. For example you can print 'Hello World!` in next way:

```
php -r "echo 'Hello World!';"
```

Comment: It is not working. There is the output.
[root@13-233-227-17 ~]# php -r "echo 'Hello World';"
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r